# How to enable non-SSL or weakly encrypted access for old browsers?

Tags: ssl

A given Apache website has to be accessible by old (~15 years) browsers on specific devices. This is why as a last resort I would have to give up encryption at all. But I would still like to make it as safe as possible.

One attempt was to allow weak ciphers. But Apache doc says (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html):

> Beginning with version 2.4.7, null and export-grade ciphers are always disabled, as mod_ssl unconditionally adds !aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP to any cipher string at initialization.

(https://www.google.com/ does support older ciphers and loads in old browsers though.)

So it seems I can't give the old browsers any SSL with Apache. My next attempt was to redirect all clients who support SSL automatically from the http:// variant to https://, but leave those who don't on the unencrypted site. But I can't find a way to manage this.

So my best solution at the moment is to let users freely decide if they go to the encrypted or the non-encrypted version of the website, without redirect. I don't like this idea, because in my opinion every user with a decent browser should use SSL and thus be redirected from http to https automatically.

Is there a better possibility?

Comment: 15 years ago was 2008, and practically nothing in 2008 _needed_ 'export' ciphersuites; the US regulations requiring them had been dropped in 1999, and TLSv1.1 in 20026 officially deleted them although many implementations still contained them. Many 2008 things did support only ciphersuites considered _weak_ today (RC4, 1DES and 3DES but not AES, CBC rather than AEAD, no ECDSA/ECDHE, etc) but Apache hasn't (yet!) prohibited those.

Comment: Please edit your question to add specific user agents and their versions you want to support. The minimum TLS version you can enforce affects how good your transport security is, and the amount of work to enable a less-secure configuration in modern servers.

Answer (score 0):

Create an http vhost in the VirtualHost of the website. With httpd -S you can see all the vhosts.

You can also add the old ciphers to the ssl block of the vhost
Here is an example of the configuration for a allowing cipher suite

SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS

See also this thread
https://superuser.com/questions/882638/sslciphersuite-settings-in-apache-for-supporting-tls-1-0-1-1-and-1-2

Comment: Note if you want multiple https vhosts with different SSL/TLS parameters that requires client send SNI, and browser implementation of SNI was still spotty in 2008. However OP talks about 'a' website which sounds like only one.

Comment: That is not what i said and mean @dave